# Highchart - How do I create the attached image gauge within a semicircle

Tags: charts, highcharts

I need this type of gauge chart

[image]

How do I create the above guage chart

I have the speedometer gauge working, but it doesn't meet the needs.

Is there a way within the highchart api to use a triangle for the gauge and not the speedometer?

Comment: Current Gauge chart display
http://jsfiddle.net/ymf2zzn1/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not supported by default. However, you can achieve it wrapping `Highcharts.seriesTypes.gauge.prototype.translate` method and changing `gauge` dial element path. Check demo and code posted below.

**Wrapper code:**

```
  (function(H) {
    H.seriesTypes.gauge.prototype.translate = function() {
      var series = this,
        yAxis = series.yAxis,
        options = series.options,
        center = yAxis.center,
        pInt = H.pInt,
        merge = H.merge,
        pick = H.pick,
        isNumber = H.isNumber;

      series.generatePoints();

      series.points.forEach(function(point) {

        var dialOptions = merge(options.dial, point.dial),
          radius = (pInt(pick(dialOptions.radius, 80)) * center[2]) /
          200,
          baseLength = (pInt(pick(dialOptions.baseLength, 70)) * radius) /
          100,
          rearLength = (pInt(pick(dialOptions.rearLength, 10)) * radius) /
          100,
          baseWidth = dialOptions.baseWidth || 3,
          arrowHeight = dialOptions.arrowHeight || 10,
          arrowWidth = dialOptions.arrowWidth || 5,
          topWidth = dialOptions.topWidth || 1,
          overshoot = options.overshoot,
          rotation = yAxis.startAngleRad +
          yAxis.translate(point.y, null, null, null, true);

        // Handle the wrap and overshoot options
        if (isNumber(overshoot)) {
          overshoot = overshoot / 180 * Math.PI;
          rotation = Math.max(
            yAxis.startAngleRad - overshoot,
            Math.min(yAxis.endAngleRad + overshoot, rotation)
          );

        } else if (options.wrap === false) {
          rotation = Math.max(
            yAxis.startAngleRad,
            Math.min(yAxis.endAngleRad, rotation)
          );
        }

        rotation = rotation * 180 / Math.PI;

        point.shapeType = 'path';
        point.shapeArgs = {
          d: dialOptions.path || [
            'M', -rearLength, -baseWidth / 2,
            'L',
            baseLength, -baseWidth / 2,
            baseLength, -arrowWidth,
            baseLength + arrowHeight, topWidth / 2,
            baseLength, arrowWidth,
            baseLength, baseWidth / 2, -rearLength, baseWidth / 2,
            'z'
          ],
          translateX: center[0],
          translateY: center[1],
          rotation: rotation
        };

        // Positions for data label
        point.plotX = center[0];
        point.plotY = center[1];
      });
    }
  })(Highcharts);
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/07c3dkn4/1/

Comment: Thank you very much for replay.how we can add background image in section like

Comment: Thank you very much for replay.how can we  add image in background? For example like  https://i.imgur.com/zSm5DKp.png

Comment: You can use SVG renderer to add images. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#image

Comment: Please can you make same example in gauge chart with images

Comment: Thank you sir, for your helping me. how can i make this design look like 
https://i.imgur.com/Z2O2ZaJ.png

Please help to make similar design

Comment: This is a custom chart and will require more time to make it. You can contact Black Label company - experts in charting Highcharts. Check here: https://www.blacklabel.pl/

Comment: How we can reduce inner section width

Comment: By setting `series.pie.innerSize`. Check this: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.innerSize

Comment: Can we used high chart in production  free

Comment: Ask this question to the sales department: sales@highsoft.com. Or check here: https://shop.highsoft.com/faq